# How to share a VPN from an Android emulator to a host PC? This is the only way to bypass internet restrictions in my country

Tags: vpn, android, emulator, sharing

I ran a virtual Android called BlissOS through Virtual Box.
In Android, I use NordVPN and now I want to transfer the VPN running in BlissOS to my main host, which is Windows 10.

Is such a thing possible?

Can I use other Android emulators such as NoxPlayer or BlueStacks in this regard?

For background, all VPN connections in my country are blocked through various protocols such as TCP and UDP, therefore the possible solution is to use an Android emulator, install the Android VPN version and share the VPN to the host.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141752/discussion-on-question-by-shiny-star-how-to-share-a-vpn-from-an-android-emulator).